# Ignoring directories with glob

Tags: perl

I have some code that parses a directory to get files which hold the hostname of various devices. However I want glob to ignore directories of a certain depth is this possible? So for instance I have

```
 my @files = glob('/tftpboot/configs/*/*');
```

my folder architecture looks like

```
/tftpboot/configs/core/router1 (where router1 is a file)
/tftpboot/configs/test/router2 (where router2 is a file)
/tftpboot/configs/test/firewall/context (context is a file)
```

I want to get files router1, router2 and any file of a similar depth. However I would like to ignore context any any file of that depth. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow up with:

```
@files = grep { !-d $_ } @files;
  -or-
@files = grep { -f $_ } @files;
```

You could also use something like [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule).

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->in('/tftpboot/configs');
```